# Absolute division symbol?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, terminology, divisibility

I am looking for a symbol "*" to mean "absolutely divides". For instance, by writing 
$$a^n*b$$
I mean $a^n\mid b$ but $a^{n+1}\nmid b$.

I remember I came across the symbol "$\parallel$" meaning this, but not sure if this is standard. I am not even sure if "absolutely divides" is a standard term for this meaning.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if you can't think of the symbol for something, your reader won't recognize the symbol that you use so as long as you're consistent and clear with your definition of the symbol you'll be fine with whatever you use.

Comment: @Jam True. But if there is a convention of using some particular symbols, it is better for us to follow that.

Comment: I think $||$ is standard.  In my head it reads "barely divides."

Comment: Some related older posts: [What does $p^\alpha\| n$ mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1549658),
[Let $p^k$ be the $p$-component of $a^t - 1$ i.e. $p^k\|a^t - 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/159690).
Maybe also [Notation for "the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1835552).

Comment: Even better to follow the existing convention and also explaining the convention!

Comment: p.s. I usually hear this described as "exactly divides". Although I also think I mainly see it when $a$ is prime.

Comment: @Hurkyl Well, the concept only makes sense for primes – for example, $4^1 = 2^2$, but $4^2 \nmid 8$ and $2^3 \mid 8$.